# How to transform this HTML into desired text using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

it's been nearly 20 years since I did anything with XSLT. Trying to convert docs like this HTML snippet into the text below.

```
<p>
おばあさんは、とても
<ruby><rb>喜</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>よろこ</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>びました。<br/>
「おじいさん、
<ruby><rb>今</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>こん</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>
<ruby><rb>晩</rb><rp>(</rp><rt>ばん</rt><rp>)</rp></ruby>、このたぬきで、たぬき
</p>
```

desired output

```
おばあさんは、とても<ruby=よろこ>喜</ruby>びました。<br/>
「おじいさん、
<ruby=こん>今</ruby><ruby=ばん>晩</ruby>、このたぬきで、たぬき
```

I have many pages of text I need to convert to this proprietary markup.

here's what I got started, but it's far from working as I'm struggling with handling the text outside of the ruby tags. This has long been a difficulty of XSLT right?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/p">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;p&gt;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ruby"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/p&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ruby">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="rb"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="rt"/>

</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rb">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>&lt;/ruby&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rt">
    <xsl:text>&lt;ruby=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATE**
ah I see part of the story to use `priority`

```
<xsl:template match="/p" priority="0">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;p&gt;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="ruby"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/p&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

priority is needed to ensure it doesn't get applied ahead of the templates matching "ruby" and "rt" for example.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED it

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/p" priority="0">
    <xsl:text>&lt;p&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&lt;/p&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ruby">
    <xsl:text>&lt;ruby=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rt"/>
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rb"/>
    <xsl:text>&lt;/ruby&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rb">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="rt">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="br">
    <xsl:text>&lt;br/&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Congratulation but I have no idea why you think you need priority. Other templates won't be applied over this one because other templates don't match what this one matches. There is also little point of templates that just copy the content of the element, like the absence of a template would do too.

Comment: an maybe I needed it for an earlier, intermediate stage in my progress. You are right, it seems unnecessary now that I'm better organized things!